# import non es6 libs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, three.js, es6-modules

so i have my scene set up and that wonderful stuff using import/module
but i have hit a little snag i want to use this shader:

```
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattatz/THREE.Fire/master/FireShader.js'></script>

    <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattatz/THREE.Fire/master/Fire.js'></script>
```

and i am wondering how i can import them to the module? as i can’t use the above because they load either to soon (before three.js module) or to late so the code doesn’t work any ideas of how i can use import with these two files?
or is there any other tricks i can use?

Thank you for reading

Comment: Copy the code and paste it into your own file. It's only about a hundred lines.

Comment: I copied into the module and it throws this error 'uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property FireShader, object is not extensible' works perfectly fine outside the mod though